# Visual Studio scaffolded Create form does not work in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, visual-studio-2022, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm fairly new to .NET Core and I'm working on a mini project, an apartment booking website.

I've already made my data models and data tables for the site. When I scaffold a new controller with Razor views, the create form just doesn't work when there is a foreign key in the table.

The basic create for simple tables works. I tried everything, I gave ChatGPT all of my code and it still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

There are 2 data tables `Apartments` and `Bookings`. Here are the 2 data classes which are needed in the form (they inherit their `ID` from `BaseEntity`):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vendeghazak.Data
{
    public class Booking : BaseEntity
    {
        public int GuestID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
        public string? Comment { get; set; }
        public string? Status { get; set; }
        public bool Cancelled { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ApartmentId")]
        public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
        public Apartment Apartment { get; set; }
        
        public int NumberOfPersons { get; set; }
        public int PersonsUnder18 { get; set; }
        public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public string BillingEmail { get; set;}
    }

    public class Apartment : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried removing the `Id` from the foreign key annotation, but it didn't help. When I submit the form, the `Apartments` subkey always be null and the `ModelState` is invalid because of that. There is a dropdown list for the apartments and I tried different methods to populate it correctly, without success.

I also tried hard coding the ID value of the apartment into the view then manually assign it in the controller, but the `Apartments` subkey is always null after submission.

What am I doing wrong?